# Credit card payments on mobile websites

Tags: payments, pci-compliance

I am quite confused regarding PCI requirements.
Say if I want to develop a mobile web browser based shopping portal, am I allowed to? Under the PCI requirements?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a website available on the web for normal browsers that has been made to be responsive then the device being used to access it is irrelevant.

If you are creating your own payment portal then there are other mobile considerations (to make the user experience a nicer one), but if you are using 3rd party tools I know that PayPal have a mobile payments API.

Comment: Specifically, I am thinking of using WorldPay XMLDirect for a website that will be responsive to mobile web browsers. I need the experience to stay within my own environment. Presumably, from your 1st statement, you are saying the device is irrelevant in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The PCI requirements are about the devices processing the payments. If you use others people's services (and so their devices and networks) then they are going to do a lot of the work. However, once you've picked a third party to process the payments, then see what they say specifically about PCI. For example, here's what [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/pcicompliance) say.